# Android Delete row from Database using UrlConnection

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I'm Having problem trying to delete a row from database using UrlConnection POST Method. I send the id and perform delete query based on the id but still not working

```
public String  performPostCall(String requestURL,HashMap<String, String> postDataParams) {
    URL url;
    String response = "";
    try {
        url = new URL(requestURL);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
        writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        os.close();
        int responseCode=conn.getResponseCode();

        if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            String line;
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            while ((line=br.readLine()) != null) {
                response+=line;
            }
        }
        else {
            response="";

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return response;
}
private String getPostDataString(HashMap<String, String> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;
    for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()){
        if (first)
            first = false;
        else
            result.append("&");

        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
        result.append("=");
        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
    }

    return result.toString();
}
```

I don't get any error but no result returned and no row is removed from table

```
    <?php
try{
    $db_name="magazinbd";
    $db_pass="";
    $db_user="root";
    $db_host="localhost";
    $bdd = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name;charset=utf8",$db_user, $db_pass);
    $val=$_POST['idc'];
    $req=$bdd->prepare('DELETE FROM administrateur WHERE idadmin=:idcl');
    $req->bindValue(":idcl",$val);
    $req->execute();

      if($req->rowCount())
          {
             $result="true";    
          }  
          elseif(!$req->rowCount())
          {
                $result="false";
          }

    echo $result;   
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo "erreur de connexion".$e->getmessage();
    }

?>
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: I don't get any error. it's just no data returned. in my php file I return a message but it seems like the connection is not built

Comment: I did print it in php file I get it from java file but it's NULL

Comment: How can I do that ?

Comment: I got idc=4 I tried to delete user with id 4 but this shouldn't be the returned result for rowCount() function in php file

Comment: the result should be true or false

Comment: but the delete query is not executed. after running my code I check the table and the row is not deleted yet

Answer (score 0):

```
$req->bindValue(":idcl",$val);
```

should read

```
$req->bindValue(":idcl",$val,PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Comment: I'm passing a string value I think that's the problem

Comment: So this should then have a positive effect. If so: Approve the answer :)